# Easy to generate subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, finitely-generated

Which subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$ can be generated in polynomial or subexponential time?

Comment: You can generate any subgroup of $S_n$ with $\log(|S_n|)=\log(n!)$ elements which is polynomial in $n$. But presumably you mean another measure -- please specify.

Comment: @ahulpke, The graph isomorphism problem can be reduced to finding hidden subgroup in a symmetric group but generating such group canno be done in polynomial time in $n$. Right?

Comment: Since you're talking about complexity, what is your input (and how encoded) and what is your output?

Comment: @ahulpke, the inputs are sampled from the group elements. They are encoded as their irreps. Is there any other way to encode?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. You just input some random group elements? In all irreducible representations? How does this relate to the subgroup?

Comment: @ahulpke, I cannot think of better inputs. How is generally a group is input?